# SQL Insert skip entry

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert, constraints

I have a SQL Query for PHP/MySQL and following problem:

```
INSERT INTO UserConnected(UID1, UID2) VALUES ('1','2'),('1','3'),('1','4');
```

So the problem is, that if there is one User of UID2 not available in UserAccounts (foreign key from UserConnected to UserAccount) the entire query will break and nothing will be inserted at all.

So lets say for some reaseon User 4 had been deleted already and this query is executed because the ID comes from any other source (lets say facebook, or google) it will try to insert but it cant because user is not available.

Is there a way to say, if key fails, dont insert and continue with the next element, without making several querys/calls. I would prefer to do that in one query.

Thank you very much! Best regards!

Comment: Since you've tagged this as `SQL` in addition to `MySQL` I'd like to point out that this syntax is `MySQL` specific and is not standard `SQL` so beware if you want to port your database in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. IGNORE Unfortuately does not work: #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (Database.UserConnected, CONSTRAINT UID2_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (UID2) REFERENCES UserAccount (UID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) It works when I manually delete the insert value for the not available user but the query will be dynamic and I need a way to insert all available user accounts and skip the unknow.

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO UserConnected(UID1, UID2) VALUES ('1','2'),('1','3')('1','4');
```

Comment: please try this and let me know

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. IGNORE Unfortuately does not work:

#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`Database`.`UserConnected`, CONSTRAINT `UID2_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`UID2`) REFERENCES `UserAccount` (`UID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) 

It works when I delete the InserValue for the not available user

Comment: np,if it fixed that's all.

Comment: But is there another way. The query is dynamic and it wont work if it builds one with a user that is not available anymore. For example I use Facebook Login to get all friends of a user and save theses in my database. The Facebook API gives me all user-Accounts that have installed the application somehow. If a user got deleted from database but did not delete the application from his facebook account, it will send back his ID and the query tries to insert this. If there is a way to say, ignore insert for that element if not possible and continue with next it would work perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO UserConnected(UID1, UID2) VALUES ('1','2'),('1','3'),('1','4');
```

Your are missing comma in last value set